# apex query error with local variable

Tags: apex, soql, query

This my query :

```
Date todayDate = date.today();
    PropositionCommerciales = [SELECT 
                                    Id,
                                    Compte__c.Id AccountId,
                                    Societe__c Societe,
                                    Agence__c.Societe__c ASociete,
                                    RecordType.Name 
                                FROM PropositionCommerciale__c 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (RecordType.Name IN ('Ponctuel',''))
                                            AND 
                                        (((:todayDate - DateFinPrestation__c)*24*60)/365) > 2 //2 ans

                                    )
                                    OR
                                    (
                                        (RecordType.Name IN ('Permanent',''))
                                            AND 
                                        ((:todayDate - DateFinPrestation__c)*24*60) > 61 //2 mois
                                            AND
                                        FrequenceFacturation__c == 'Mensuelle'
                                    )

                                ];
```

I have two errors :

> 1) Unexpected token ':'.

And when i delete ":" (to get the local variable date), i have this second error.

> 2) line 12, col 80. Unexpected token ')'.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details what exactly you want to achieve from this SOQL query? On other note, you can perform such calculation in your SOQL query where clause.

Comment: I sure you cannot do these operations using local variables and SOQL. Like this one *:todayDate*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform such calculation in your SOQL query where clause. Either you should be using the [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) or get the exact value which you can use against the right operand in SOQL filters.

```
DateFinPrestation__c > LAST_N_YEARS:2
```

Above statement will query records where DateFinPrestation__c date is from last 2 years.

Or, there is an alternative way where you need to first calculate a date which needs to be compared against the record's specific date field.

Example -
Date dtFinPrestation = Date.today().addYears(-2); // Date before 2 years

```
DateFinPrestation__c > :dtFinPrestation
```